# Using Highcharts, I want to overlay a line showing the optimal value for a bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to overlay 2 diagonal lines over top of a negative stacked bar chart. The purpose of these lines is to show where the optimal value for each bar should be.

The chart will always be from -10% to 10% along the x-axis, so the lines do not need to scale smaller if the graph grew. (though that would be nice to know how to do that as well if it's a small addition)

I am relatively new to HighCharts and I can't seem to find out if this is possible or not.

[image]

Comment: Will the intersection of the diagonal bars change or are they static?

Comment: They are static, the example you put up did it exactly, when I brought  it into my project though the line1 did not act the same. See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Joey2250/G2MRy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the intersection of the lines are always going to intersect at the same point I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/4tTWH/3/). What I did was create two additional series that go from -10 to 0 and 10 to 0. You could do this with one series as well but maybe the male/female projection lines are different? Your choice.

Now, since I do not know where the two lines should intersect I had them end at the final category. You can adjust this by giving the two series different end points. The other trick is to fill the 2 projection lines with null for the in-between points and allow the 2 end points to be connected. I also hid the markers, hid the series from the legend, and allowed for different line styles.
Important bits:

```
{
        name: 'line1',
        type: 'line',
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        connectNulls: true,
        showInLegend: false,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        data: [0, null},
            ...
            , 10]}
```

Since these data series are stacked we need to make sure only those series get stacked otherwise the 2 projected lines get stacked as well. Do this via:

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        //pointWidth: 20
    }
},
```

Note that is only applying stacking to the 'bar' types. Update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2MRy/3/).

Comment: This has been a huge help! I am having a problem with the formatting of line1, It is going from -10 to +10 and I'm not sure why. Line2 correctly goes from -10 to 0 diagonally. Here is the link to my JSFiddle. I added empty bars at the top and bottom so the diagonal would go above and below the actual bars. http://jsfiddle.net/Joey2250/G2MRy/

Comment: Investigating issue. Oh, I did make a bit of an error in my example. You only need the marker: {enabled: false} in the series properties not on all the data points. That still does not solve this odd issue.

Comment: @Joey2250, Looking at your chart image in the question and your jsFiddle your pyramid has shifted direction. The 65+ age group has "more" value than the 4 and under group. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: JHere you go: http://jsfiddle.net/G2MRy/3/ Your problem was the stacking of the chart. You need to only apply the stacking to the bar series. Updated my answer to show code clearer.

Comment: This is an example showing a 'top-heavy' graph. The values for the bars will change on user input, but the optimal value lines will always stay the same. from (-10,0)to (0,16) & (16,0) to (0,10) [note: the y-value goes to 16 because of the 2 empty spaces, 1 at the top and 1 at the bottom, there are only 14 actual bars that will appear]

Comment: That is perfect! I just reversed the +,- to get the pyramid to show the reverse way & its exactly how I want it!. http://jsfiddle.net/Joey2250/G2MRy/4/ Thank you so much for your help! Now I just need to get enough rep to upvote your answer.

Comment: Yep, population trending is interesting. Just wanted to make sure the data presentation I was working with was what you wanted. I work in labor market information myself. Change of chart properties and woah...you see something you did not see before.

Comment: You can get more rep by accepting the answer if it helped. Not obliged to but if it did work out for you then go ahead.